# Change title attribute dynamically

Tags: javascript, golden-layout

I'm trying to add custom tooltip for the control icons in GoldenLayout.

So far what i've done is, i'm finding the class of each controller icons and adding a new attribute called `tooltip` and removing the `title` attribute.

Which works fine for the `close` & `open in new window`, but for the `minimise` and `maximise` i need to set the `tooltip` value dynamically and also need to remove the `title` attribute

I'm unable to achieve that functionality . Please help

Full code https://jsfiddle.net/sutgfg1y/

```js
myLayout.on('stackCreated', function(stack) {

  stack
    .header
    .controlsContainer
    .find('.lm_close') //get the close icon
    .attr('tooltip', 'Close')
    .removeAttr('title')
  stack
    .header
    .controlsContainer
    .find('.lm_popout') //get the close icon
    .attr('tooltip', 'Open in new window')
    .removeAttr('title')
  stack
    .header
    .controlsContainer
    .find('.lm_maximise')
    .attr('tooltip', 'maxi')
    .removeAttr('title')
    .click(function() {
      var maxi = stack
        .header
        .controlsContainer
        .find('.lm_maximise')
        .attr('tooltip')
      alert(maxi)
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hold the current value of the tooltip in a variable.  Toggle that value on click, and reset the tooltip...

```
myLayout.on('stackCreated', function(stack) {
  // Keep track of the state of the tooltip
  var minMax = 'maximize';

  stack
    .header
    .controlsContainer
    .find('.lm_close') //get the close icon
    .attr('tooltip', 'Close')
    .removeAttr('title')
  stack
    .header
    .controlsContainer
    .find('.lm_popout') //get the close icon
    .attr('tooltip', 'Open in new window')
    .removeAttr('title')
  stack
    .header
    .controlsContainer
    .find('.lm_maximise')
    .attr('tooltip', minMax) // Set the starting value
    .removeAttr('title')
    .click(function() {
      // Verify what your click just did
      var maxi = stack
        .header
        .controlsContainer
        .find('.lm_maximise')
        .attr('tooltip');
      alert(maxi);

      // Toggle the tooltip
      minMax = minMax === 'maximize' ? 'minimize' : 'maximize';
      stack
        .header
        .controlsContainer
        .find('.lm_maximise')
        .attr('tooltip', minMax);
    })
});
```